# Can you retract reopen votes?

Tags: support, re-open, closing

I recently, for a miss-guided reason (it is complicated, but my logic was in error) clicked to re-open a meta question which I believe should be left closed. I immediately tried to retract my vote, but found that I could not.

> Can you retract a re-open vote?

If not, why not?

Comment: relevant feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193061/